# Replace 12 MS apps with a single ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I wonder if you could give your opinion on something I am working on right now?
 We have 12  MS Access applications that look quite similar in terms of data and functionality: each app allows 12 practices to capture data for services they provide  to patients. The practices cover physical therapy, orthotics, speech and language , social services , etc. 6 are for inpatients and 6 for outpatients.

I built a  MS SQL database to replace the 12 apps  and respective 12 databases. The model looks pretty good and I think it will scale well.

Now  I am working on designing an asp.net web forms app to replace the above 12 apps.  My dilemma is: how should I approach this challenge?

In the current version of the apps, each data entry screen looks almost the same amongst practices; there are a few cosmetic changes and fields may be laid out differently but the result is the same: allow the user to enter service codes for work performed on their patients.

So, say that for each app, we have a page called charges.aspx which will look almost the same per practice.

My question is: should i build 12 similar pages, one for each of the old apps, since the data entry is very similar? Or, maybe, generate the UI, previoulsy defined in sql using something like a template for each practice?

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Regards,

Huambo

Comment: I'm thinking user controls for your fields and  a masterpage with shared functionality should already minimize the re-use of code a lot.  I assume that all applications are fairly simple in their UI design.

Comment: Thank you for your message! Yes, the ui is not too complicated: about 12 data entry fields and 2 grid controls.

Answer (score 0):

Put the security and user handling code in the masterpage.

If you have a field or a block of fields that you have to re-use ( patient basic information),
make a user control with those fields on it.

Please look at jQuery to simplify the client side of your code. jQuery.UI can provide usefull control out-of-the-box!